# jQuery set each problem

Tags: jquery, function, each

i have a problem with an $.each in a jQuery function, as I have the following function:

`function set_max(unit) {`

```
var max = parseInt($("#"+unit+"_area").html().replace('(','').replace(')',''));
if (max > 0) {
    $("[name="+unit+"]").val(max);
    $("[name=area]").html('(0)');
} else {
    var val = $("#"+unit+"_area").attr('max');
    $("[name="+unit+"]").val('');
    $("#"+unit+"_area").html('('+val+')');
    $.each($("[name=area]"),function(){
        var caller = $(this).attr('id');
        vall = $("#"+caller+"_area").attr('max');
        $(caller).html('('+vall+')');
    });
}
```

}

But the each part doesnt work, as the .html() parts from the link remain 0.
The links are like this:

`<a id="spear_area" name="area" max="5812" href="javascript:set_max('spear');">(5812)</a>`

Comment: make sure you pass a radix to `parseInt`.

Comment: Ah, i solved my problem,


    $.each($("[name=area]"),function(){
    var caller = $(this).attr('id');
    vall = $("#"+caller).attr('max');
    $("#"+caller).html('('+vall+')');
    });

The $.each part had some id finding problems.

Comment: this is very likly the ugliest piece of javascript/jquery code i have ever seen.. you may want to replace $.each by $(selector).each, take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/each)

Comment: Niko, i am a beginner. If i knew that there was a better solution, it was very likely that i wouldn't even post here. And it seems that my ugly piece of code works, since i verified both each parts from -Link and Dennis, and none work, but my ugly comment does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the regular `each` instead.  $.fn.each is designed for iterating over jQuery objects whereas $.each iterates over regular objects/arrays.

```
$("[name=area]").each(function(){
    var caller = $(this).attr('id');
    vall = $("#"+caller+"_area").attr('max');
    $(caller).html('('+vall+')');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The syntax of $.each() is incorrect:

   .each( function(index, Element) ) Returns: jQuery
2. The variable caller isn't referencing the jQuery object correctly, you should add the "#" before the ID in either of the locations below:

   var caller = "#" + $(this).attr('id');

OR

```
 $("#" + caller).html('('+vall+')');
```

Your code should become:

```
function set_max(unit) {
    var max = parseInt($("#"+unit+"_area").html().replace('(','').replace(')',''));

    if (max > 0) {

        $("[name="+unit+"]").val(max);
        $("[name=area]").html('(0)');

    } else {    

        var val = $("#"+unit+"_area").attr('max');
        $("[name="+unit+"]").val('');
        $("#"+unit+"_area").html('('+val+')');

        $("a[name=area]").each(function() {
            var caller = "#" + $(this).attr('id');
            vall = $("#"+caller+"_area").attr('max');
            $(caller).html('('+vall+')');
        });

    }
}
```